# How to browse map in hazelcast mancenter?

Tags: hazelcast

I have data in my hazelacst and in GUI mancenter everything works. But when I want to browse data in my cache I got error 500 from rest:

```
{"value":{"1659345376000":{"offsetReader"}}}{"error":{"type":"GENERAL_EXCEPTION","message":"An exception occurred: Type definition error: [simple type, class com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.compact.OffsetReader$$Lambda$2167/0x00000008016c29f8]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.compact.OffsetReader$$Lambda$2167/0x00000008016c29f8 and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: com.hazelcast.webmonitor.service.MapEntryViewDTO[\"value\"]->java.util.TreeMap[\"1659345376000\"]->com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.compact.DefaultCompactReader[\"offsetReader\"])"}}
```

in hazelcast I got custom class using compact serialization with my custom serializer. I got no problem when reading or writing data to cache just GUI not working as I expected. So GUI can not work with custom class ?

Answer (score 0):

Management Center supports compact serialization.

Is your Management Center configured to use the custom serializer? (https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/5.2-beta-1/serialization/compact-serialization#latest-banner `Declarative configuration`) and https://docs.hazelcast.com/management-center/5.1/deploy-manage/connecting-to-clusters-ui#using-a-client-configuration-file

Is you custom serializer class present in the Management Center classpath? (https://docs.hazelcast.com/management-center/5.1/getting-started/install#starting-with-scripts `Put your classes in the bin/user-lib/ directory.`)

Comment: I am instaling with helm in kubernetes cluster with my own image where I add custom jar: ADD rob-hazelcast-cache-1.0.jar ${HZ_HOME}. So this add jar just to client and I need to add this to mancenter too ? Where exactly

Comment: You need to add your JAR to `bin/user-lib/` dir in MC. 
And then when you configure MC to cluster connection you need to provide XML or YAML connection config where the custom serializer is specified. Please see the links from the answer for more details.
If you don't use a custom serializer for Compact, all these steps aren't needed, MC will work with Compact serialized objects out of the box.